# Windows Universal App Development Template Load error

Tags: win-universal-app, windows-10, windows-10-iot-core

it's quite annoying now just finished with the setup and when trying to build a "Hello World" Application with Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
Error: this template attempted to load component assembly 
'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Universal.TemplateWizards, Version=14.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. For more information 
on this problem and how to enable this template, please see documentation 
on Customizing Project Templates.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Now I don't understand what wrong with it.  I tried the comunity edition on Windows 8.1 and able to build the apps. but when trying with Enterprise Edition on Windows 10, nothing excepts Error.

Nor Information page list any tools for development.

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2015
Version 14.0.23107.0 D14REL
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.6.00079

Installed Version: Enterprise

Architecture and Modeling Tools   00322-80000-00000-AA627
Microsoft Architecture and Modeling Tools

UML® and Unified Modeling Language™ are trademarks or registered trademarks of the Object Management Group, Inc. in the United States and other countries.

Visual Basic 2015   00322-80000-00000-AA627
Microsoft Visual Basic 2015

Visual C# 2015   00322-80000-00000-AA627
Microsoft Visual C# 2015

Visual C++ 2015   00322-80000-00000-AA627
Microsoft Visual C++ 2015

Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio Package   1.0
Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio

ASP.NET and Web Tools   14.0.20711.0
ASP.NET and Web Tools

ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2013   5.2.30624.0
For additional information, visit http://www.asp.net/

Common Azure Tools   1.5
Provides common services for use by Azure Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.

GenerateUnitTest   1.0
Generates unit test code for methods in classes under test.

GitHub.VisualStudio   1.0
A Visual Studio Extension that brings the GitHub Flow into Visual Studio.

Indent Guides   14
Indent Guides

Adds visual guides at each indentation level.

Microsoft Azure HDInsight HQL Service   2.0.2200.0
Language service for Hive query

Microsoft Azure HDInsight Tools for Visual Studio   2.0.2200.0
An integrated development environment for HDInsight application development.

Microsoft Azure Mobile Services Tools   1.4
Microsoft Azure Mobile Services Tools

Microsoft Code Digger   0.9
Microsoft Code Digger

Microsoft.Pex.VisualStudio   1.0
Pex

NuGet Package Manager   3.0.0
NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio. For more information about NuGet, visit http://docs.nuget.org/.

PreEmptive Analytics Visualizer   1.2
Microsoft Visual Studio extension to visualize aggregated summaries from the PreEmptive Analytics product.

SQL Server Data Tools   14.0.50616.0
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools

Web Essentials 2015   0.5.144
Adds many useful features to Visual Studio for web developers.
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I had the same issue on Windows 10 in VirtualBox.

You must run the visual studio installer again.
Select "Modify" in the Installer.
Select Features > "Windows and Web Development" > "Universal Windows App Development Tools" > Click Update / Install.

Now you will be able to use the vs project template Windows IoT Core.

Answer (score 2):

If such an error came up upon a project from a DirectX project template then make sure you have the UWP workload installed (from Visual Studio Installer).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have xamarin for visual studio disabled. Select Tools > "Extensions en Updates" > "Xamarin For visual studio" > Click Enabled.

Answer (score 0):

you can find solution in here.

https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates/issues/7

### above site said,

A workaround for this is to edit C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe.config and add to the  section:

```
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Universal.TemplateWizards" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/>
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="14.0.0.0" newVersion="15.0.0.0"/>
</dependentAssembly>
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.VisualStudio.WinRT.TemplateWizards" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/>
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="14.0.0.0" newVersion="15.0.0.0"/>
</dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: Can you provide the gist of the solution, rather than just including a link? Links can depreciate over time and the answer will be lost to future readers.